# FSCrawler docker-compose NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, elasticsearch, fscrawler

I try to run FSCrawler via docker-compose following the steps described in https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/fscrawler-2.9/installation.html#using-docker-compose.

```
ELASTIC_VERSION = "7.17.8"  
FSCRAWLER_VERSION = "2.9"  
PWD = ""
```

I verified that elasticsearch is running sucessfully.

On running `docker-compose up fscrawler`, I get the following exception.

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 2.10-SNAPSHOT which is much more stable although the name does not say that ;)

Comment: Could you create a new post or update the original one with this new information? Because it seems to be totally unrelated to the original issue.